# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: with priority queue and comparator

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator, compareto

What is wrong with this code. I am getting below error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Nodes cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(Unknown Source)
```

please help

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

class Nodes implements Comparator<Nodes> {
        public int n;
        public int c;

        public Nodes() {
        }

        public Nodes(int n, int c) {
            this.n = n;
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Nodes Nodes1, Nodes Nodes2) {
            if (Nodes1.c < Nodes2.c) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (Nodes1.c > Nodes2.c) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
class dj
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Queue<Nodes> pq = new PriorityQueue<Nodes>();
    pq.add(new Nodes(5,4));
   pq.add(new Nodes(6,7));
   pq.add(new Nodes(7,6));
   pq.add(new Nodes(8,9));
   pq.add(new Nodes(9,8));
   pq.add(new Nodes(8,8));  

    }
}
```

Comment: You probably ment to implement Comparable, not Comparator

Comment: And hint: the *real* thing here to learn: learn to read exception messages - they tell you **exactly** what is going on! That is one of the big things when learning programming: you have to pay attention to such subtle details as "Comparator" not being the same as "Comparable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because you implemented the wrong interface.

What you need is

```
class Nodes implements Comparable<Nodes>
```

This indicates that the Nodes class can be compared to other Nodes.
Which is what is required to use it in a PriorityQueue.

A Comparator is a Class that compares Objects even if they do not implement Comparable themself. It can often be passed to specific sort functions and is usually independent of the Class itself  (You can have multiple Comparator with different logic)

See the JavaDoc of the 2 Classes for more information:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: To make your answer perfect, you could put in the Javadoc links yourself ;-)